# Nuxt 3 csrf token issue

Tags: vue.js, frontend, csrf, nuxtjs3, go-echo

I am actually a backend developer but recently I became curious about nuxt3 and started developing a basic CRUD app. I created two separate apps for BE and FE for BE I used Go with Echo, but when I try to implement the CSRF token middleware to the BE it always started giving me the error. But when I use postman every thing works as it should be with no errors.

```
message "invalid csrf token"
```

I tried every solution I find using useFetch of vue and Axios didn't solve my problem.

on go side, I used default methods and didn't add a custom one

```
app.Use(middleware.CSRF())
```

Also defined CORS middleware

```
app.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
    AllowOrigins: []string{os.Getenv("APP_CLIENT_URL")},
    AllowHeaders: []string{
        echo.HeaderOrigin,
        echo.HeaderContentType,
        echo.HeaderAccept,
        echo.HeaderAuthorization,
        echo.HeaderXCSRFToken,
    },
}))
```

And I am returning the generated csrf to the FR via a endpoint

```
func CsrfHandler(c echo.Context) error {
    token := c.Get("csrf").(string)

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, utils.Response(
        true,
        "CSRF token generated successfully",
        models.Token{
            Token:     token,
            ExpiresAt: "",
        }))
}
```

After here I can display token on the FE side but for some reason getting 403 code.

On nuxt3 side
for getting csrf-token

```
export const useCsrf = () => {
    const csrfToken = ref('')
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    async function fetchCsrfToken() {
        await useFetch('/csrf-token', {
                baseURL: config.public.baseUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                onResponse({ response}): Promise<void> | void {
                    csrfToken.value = response._data.data.token
                },
                onRequestError({ error }) {
                    console.log('request error', error)
                },
            },
        )
    }

    onMounted(fetchCsrfToken)

    return {
        csrfToken,
    }
}
```

this is the method I use for creating user

```
const createUser = async (user: UserInterface, csrfToken: string) => {
    await useFetch('/api/create-user', {
        baseURL: config.public.baseUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        body: user,
        onRequest({ options }) {
            options.headers = {
                'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('api_key')}`
            }
        },
        onRequestError({ error }) {
            console.log('request error', error)
        }
    })
}
```

On postman I display a Cookie header but as I know since Set-Cookie parameter for http only I cant reach it and it is a security issue. So I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your help.